# Problem with fetch API while deploying MERN app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, fetch, mern

I'm trying to deploy a MERN app on Heroku but am having problem with the fetch API. The following code gives the error **"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0"** in the console.

```
getDataFromDb = () => {
   fetch('https://product-listing-listing.herokuapp.com/api/getData')
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((res) => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
};
```

And skipping the root, just writing `fetch('/api/getData')` gives the same error.

Whereas when I run the app locally with npm start with the following code, I get no errors:

```
getDataFromDb = () => {
   fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/getData')
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((res) => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you look at what the response body is? Is it JSON? Did the request even succeed - what's the status code?

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0` means that `fetch('https://product-listing-listing.herokuapp.com/api/getData')` returns a invalid JSON result.

try

```js
getDataFromDb = () => {
   fetch('https://product-listing-listing.herokuapp.com/api/getData')
      .then((data) => data.text())
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
};
```

to inspect what `fetch` returns.